# Find the smallest possible value for $x^2-3x+2y^2+4y+2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Find the smallest possible value for $x^2-3x+2y^2+4y+2$.

I know this: $x^2-3x+2y^2+4y+2=(x-\frac{3}{2})^2+2(y+1)^2-\frac{9}{4}$ so the smallest value is $-\frac{9}{4}$.

Now we also know this: $x^2-3x+2y^2+4y+2=(x-1)^2-1-x+2(y+1)^2=(*)(x-1)^2+2(y+1)^2-(1+x)$

My question is: why we cannot say that the smallest value possible is $-(1+x)$ when $(x-1)^2=0$ (i.e. when $x=1$) and $(y+1)^2=0$, and because $x=1$ so the smallest value is $-2$?

Comment: $(x-1)^2-(1+x)$ is not smallest for $x=1$ because then $(x-1)^2$ is zero, but $(1+x)$ is not that big. 
Better is $x=1.5$ because then $(x-1)^2$ is still small but $(1+x)$ is bigger.

Comment: A value is a real number. $-(1+x)$ is a function.

Comment: Good question! Well, $-\frac{9}{4}$ is independent of x, but $-(1+x)$ is not.

Comment: @Henry that's a good way of putting it.

Comment: $-(1+x)$ is not a single value.  ANd although $(x-1)^2$ is it's smallest when $x-1=0$ we have no idea at all whether $-(1+x)$ is at it's smallest there as well.  If fact it isn't as $-(1+x) = -2$ but if $x=\frac 32$ then $-(1+x) = -2\frac 12 < -2$.  And if we take $x > \frac 32$ we get $-(1+x)$ is even smaller.  The thing we have to solve is when $(x-1)^2$ *AND* $-(1+x)$ take *TOGETHER* are at their combined smallest.  We can't just take one at its smallest.

Answer (score 9):

If you (think you) have completed the square, but your left-over term isn't a constant, then you haven't completed the square.

The fact that $x=1$ minimises the expression $(x-1)^2$ has nothing to do with minimising $g_1(x) = (x-1)^2 + 3x\ $ or $\ g_2(x) =(x-1)^2 - 26x^3 + 45,\ $ or $\ g_3(x) =(x-1)^2 + f(x),\ $ unless $f(x)$ is a constant.

If $f(x)$ is a constant, for example, $\ g_3(x) = (x-1)^2 + 24,\ $ then $x=1$ minimises $\ g_3(x)\ $; the reason being that $\ \min \{ u^2: u\in\mathbb{R} \} = 0.\quad g_3(x)$ attains this minimum when $x=1.$

This reasoning goes out the window for $g_1(x), $ because $g_1(x) = (x+1/2)^2 + 3/4,$ and so the minimum of $\ g_1(x)\ $ is $\ 3/4\ $ occurs when $x=-1/2.$

Comment: thank you ......

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-3x+2y^2+4y+2=0$ is an ellipse, so what do you mean by "the smallest possible value of $x^2-3x+2y^2+4y+2$"?
Anyway, since you have two distinct values of $y=y(x)$ for the given $x: x=\frac{3}{2}$ such that one of them (the negative one) is minimum, I will write only the positive value of $y(x) : x=\frac{3}{2}$, leaving the final step (and its proof) as an exercise.
Well, $y\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) : y>0$ is equal to $\left(\frac{3}{2\cdot \sqrt{2}} - 1\right)$ so that you have to show why $y\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) : y<0$ is the minimum and then find the value.

P.S. If we are just interested in the global minimum of $x^2-3x+2y^2+4y+2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is at $(x,y)=(\frac{3}{2},-1)$ and it is $-\frac{9}{4}$ indeed.

Comment: thank you ......